# Can you reference functions from other classses using namespaces without ::?

Tags: c++

So could you? As an example, you can print a line out onto the screen using `std::cout << "Message";` but if you add `using namespace std;` to the top of your code you can then use it without the `std::` and just use it as `cout << "Message";`

Can you do that with your own code?

Edit: Let me explain better.

Let's say I have class A:

```
//Class A
#include <iostream>
#include "A.h"
using namespace std;
class A {
public: void testFunction() {
cout << "My message";
}
};
```

Then, providing I have headers setup correctly, I would be able to do:

```
//Class B
#include <iostream>
#include "A.h"
using namespace std;

class B {
int main() {
A aObject; //Create the object
aObject.testFunction(); //This is how I'd have to reference it
return 0;
}
};
```

So what I'm wondering, is whether, even though it's in a seperate class, how to reference that function using just `testFunction()` rather than `aObject.testFunction()`

Comment: _"Can you do that with your own code?"_ Of course you can do this for your user defined namespaces the same way. What are you actually asking about?

Comment: yes. you can. [readthis](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_namespaces.htm)

Comment: if you want behaviour like `using namespace MyClass;`, then no - at least I have not heard of it.

Comment: *"Let's say I have class A"* There is no `class A` in your code. Neither is there a `class B`. There's only `A aObject` in your `main` function.

Comment: @dyp I know that, they are just examples. I just typed them out really quick, so at least you guys knew what I was on about.

Comment: But those examples don't make sense to me. Your question is about *classes*, but there are no classes in your code.

Comment: Thanks. I suppose at least `A::testFunction` should be `public`?

Comment: @dyp Whoops, once again I was typing the code really quick. Wasn't really paying a lot of attention to what I was writing, I was just trying to write enough for people to understand what I was on about :P.

Answer (score 1):

Non-static member functions of a class can only be called on an object of that class. That's what they are for. You don't have to have a named object but you still have to have an object:

```
A().testFunction();
```

If you make the function `static` then you can call it like this:

```
A::testFunction();
```

It doesn't make any sense to talk about calling that function in any other way. This is how member functions work. It sounds like you really want a non-member function, perhaps in a namespace.

Answer (score 0):

here is an example from [tutorialspoint](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_namespaces.htm):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

// first name space
namespace first_space{
   void func(){
      cout << "Inside first_space" << endl;
   }
}
// second name space
namespace second_space{
   void func(){
      cout << "Inside second_space" << endl;
   }
}
using namespace first_space;
int main ()
{

   // This calls function from first name space.
   func();

   return 0;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Perhaps this will clarify it even more:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

// first name space
namespace first_space{
   void func(){
      cout << "Inside first_space" << endl;
   }
   // second name space
   namespace second_space{
      void func(){
         cout << "Inside second_space" << endl;
      }
   }
}
using namespace first_space::second_space;
int main ()
{

   // This calls function from second name space.
   func();

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Question was _"..from other classes.."_ not other namespaces. Also please don't copy paste post from other sources

Comment: oh, i am sorry. Classes are not meant for that, it will violate encapsulation and data abstraction.

Answer (score 0):

If u want to call a method(say in class A) only by its name then it will create ambiguities when there is a method with same name,parameters,return type in another class(say class B) that is also included in the header.